# Feature request : View featured questions "latest first"

Tags: feature-request

I would like to be able to view the list of featured questions ordered according to "latest first", contrary to the default mode of "oldest first" which is tiresome because it forces you to scroll down to the bottom of the  page to get the "complete list", then scroll down again  to the bottom of the page to click on the link that points to the last page.

As far as I know, this is currently not even possible with the search engine.

Comment: I have vague memories of this being possible a long long time ago, in a galaxy far away.

Answer (score 8):

This is possible with a [clever use of advanced search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=hasnotice%3a1%20is%3aq%20locked%3a0). The cleverness isn't mine:   [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200230/is-there-any-way-to-sort-bounty-questions#comment637127_200230) came up with the search query.

There are a few false positives (at the moment I get 92 search results, of which 75 are actual bounties), because a notice can be also added by a moderator. However the false positives tend to be older, and so the top of the list -- which is what you are after -- indeed has the featured questions.